# Is it possible to configure primary and secondary IP addresses of an interface via DHCP?

Tags: dhcp

I would like to assign multiple IP addresses via DHCP on the same interface. Does the DHCP protocol and DHCP servers allowing this?

Comment: why what would the purpose be?

Comment: To have multiple IPs? If you have an SSL service and you do not want to share the certificates and the service is run on the same port and it is not supporting TLS. Why DHCP? To be able to manage the IPs used by VMs in one place.

Comment: A workaround would be to get the IP from DHCP, then use a configuration engine to set the all IPs statically, but without saving the configuration. In this way the VMs do not have a IP assigned, they do not need a proprietary DHCP server/client and they can use multiple IPs. I wondering how this will scale for different OSes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DHCP Client IDs are set to different values then you *should* be able to statically allocate different addresses.  I say "should" because it's rarely done and support is sparse.

Your use case is at least partly accounted for by the spec ([RFC-2131](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131)) in that a server must use the Client ID for identification if one was provided by the client.

You might try dnsmasq.  According to the [dnsmasq FAQ](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/FAQ) (about halfway down), it treats duplicate MAC addresses with differing Client IDs as different devices.

On the client, you can set the Client ID with dhclient's ``-I [Client-ID]'' flag.

Comment: + For a Linux machine this is an good workaround.

Comment: Thanks, spent ages trying to figure out how to do this. For my purposes, installing Apache2 and rewrite rules would have been much faster, but I didn't want to install another server when the tools already existed!

Answer (score 4):

No, DHCP only provides mechanisms for assigning a single IP to any one MAC address.

Comment: I know that there are options to set the routing table and I was wondering if I can not add secondary IPs too.

Comment: No, there are no options that I know of to specify secondary IP addresses.

Comment: Well DHCP is extensible.  One could modify the DHCP client, and add custom classes on the server.  Many DHCP clients have an API.

Comment: That might have been true once upon a time, but is certainly not true now, and jbbuckley's response suggests it wasn't even true when the question was asked.